# SQL null spaces in calculated columns

Tags: sql, firebird

I have created a calculated column but it is giving me a row with null value. If I add another calculated field, it adds 2 null rows, and so on.

My objective is to get a single row with a single value. No nulls.

The code:

```
SELECT 
CLIENT_CODE, 
( CASE WHEN CLITBP.TBPCODIGO=101 THEN COALESCE( CLITBP.TBPDESC2,0) ELSE NULL END) TAB101
FROM
CLIENT
GROUP BY 1,2
```

the wrong output

[image: wrong]

the intended output

[image: right]

Comment: In the future when asking questions like this, make sure to include DDL and sample data. And don't use images where text suffices (eg you could have used a code block with your table data instead of those images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per client code, then you should have only one key in the `GROUP BY`.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT CLIENT_CODE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CLITBP.TBPCODIGO = 101 THEN COALESCE(CLITBP.TBPDESC2, 0) END) as TAB101 
FROM CLIENT
GROUP BY CLIENT_CODE;
```

Comment: Great Gordon. It worked ! Thanks a lot . Have a nice day !